# No route matches on dynamic page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a dynamic page based on the trial_id from the Trial controller. I have it showing the right url, but get a No route matches [GET] error. I'm using rails 4.2.0 and this worked previously on 3.2, but i think I'm missing something.

**View**

```
<% @regions.each do |region, list| %>
  <%= region %>
    <% list.sort{ |a,b| a.site.site_name <=> b.site.site_name }.each do |list| %>
      <% paths = trials_show_path(trial_id: list.trial_id)
         path = paths.gsub("?trial_id=", "/")
      %>

<%= link_to list.site.site_name, path %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Show Controller**

```
@results = Trial.trial_id(params[:trial_id])
```

**Trial Model**

```
scope :trial_id, -> (trial_id) { where(trial_id: trial_id) }
```

**Routes**

```
  get 'trials', :to => 'trials#index'
  get 'trials/show'
```

Comment: show your corresponding route from `routes.rb` file..

Comment: can you share the rake routes output

Comment: Added routes above. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @DollarChills do `rake routes` in terminal with current application location and check routes generated for application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom route in your `routes.rb` file.

```
get 'trials/index/:trail_id' => 'trials#index',:as=>'trails'

get 'trials/show'
```

And then use 'trails_path' in your views.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but slightly different. I needed the params on the show GET. Thanks for you're help!